# Dúvidas em cast em c

Tags: c

Se eu dou um `printf` assim:

```
int x=5, *px = &x;
printf("%d %ld\n", x, (long)px);
```

Até ai sem *Warning* nenhum, mas se mudo o `printf`:

```
int x=5, *px = &x;
printf("%d %d\n", x, (int)px);
```

Recebo um aviso:

> warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size.

Por que esse aviso? eu já entrei em alguns lugares e vi alguns operados bem diferentes '\zu' e vários outros, alguém conhece um artigo que eu possa ler só sobre esse tema? Recebo Warning toda hora.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em arquiteturas de 64 bits, ponteiros ocupam 8 bytes (ou seja, `sizeof(int*) == 8`). Por outro lado, inteiros têm 4 bytes (ou seja, `sizeof(int) == 4`). Isso pode ser comprovado facilmente:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%ld %ld", sizeof(int*), sizeof(int));
}
```

Esse código produz como saída `8 4`.

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/7wYGqs)

Quando você pega um ponteiro e faz um *cast* para inteiro, você vai estar jogando fora 4 bytes do seu valor. Isso não é problemático por si só, mas pegar um endereço de memória e jogar fora uma parte dele não é uma operação que faça lá muito sentido na prática e provavelmente vai te fornecer valores incorretos e sem serventia prática, logo o compilador te dá uma *warning*.

Comment: Compilei esse código seu e recebi esse aviso:  warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int       mas o resultado e esseq mesmo, 8 e 4

Comment: @Fernando Mudei para usar `%ld`. Isso resolve o seu warning?

Comment: Resolveu, poderia me explicar o pq ?

Comment: @Fernando Esse `l` é o prefixo para `long`, tal como explicado na tabela [**dessa página**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Comment: Obg pela ajuda, vou dar uma olhada na tabela

Answer (score 1):

Está escrito no próprio aviso. O tamanho do tipo é diferente.

Provavelmente seu int é de 16 bits e o long é 32 bits, e o ponteiro é 32 bits.

Esses tamanhos dependem da arquitetura.

### Edição

Pode ser o caso aqui, ou não, de uma pequena confusão, esclarecendo se este for o caso:
Declarar

```
int *px = &x;
```

Cria um ponteiro que aponta para o endereço da variável x, ou seja, `px` é um ponteiro. Na pergunta você está convertendo um endereço de memória para um `int` ou `long`. Para acessar o valor armazenado no endereço para o qual `px` aponta, precisa usar o "*", assim:

```
printf("%d %d\n", x, *px);
```

Isso sempre vai imprimir o mesmo valor duas vezes. Para imprimir o valor e depois o endereço, use o seu primeiro exemplo mesmo.

```
printf("%d %ld\n", x, (long)px);
```